# Another home for some Q&A

Tags: discussion

There is new question and answer site [writing.codidact.com](https://writing.codidact.com/categories/1) that is receiving the attention of SE contributors.

There is a lot of good content here at books.se and after asking on [their meta.](https://writing.codidact.com/questions/275894) I was able to confirm that they will accept posts from here that fit their scope:

> - How can I create a .pdf from a .epub file?
> - How can I export text from a .epub file?
> - What image formats can I embed in a XYZ file? (where XYZ is an ebook format)
> - What are the pros and cons of publishing in XYZ format versus ABC format?
> - What tools do I need to edit a XYZ file? (where XYZ is an ebook format)
> - Is there any software that will create an ebook from a Wordpress site?
> - Can I restrict an ebook so that it can only be read on certain devices?

All fine at writing.codidact.

> - I bought an ebook from _____. How can I read it on my Kindle/Nook/iOS device/etc.?
> - Why doesn't my Kindle/Nook/ereader show cover images?

Off-topic at writing.codidact.  But if you want to ask from the publishing side (supporting other platforms, making sure your images show up), that would be on-topic.

> - Are there any waterproof ereaders available for purchase?
> - My [ereader or electronic device] isn't working because [specific problem]; how can I fix it?

Off-topic at writing.codidact.

[Source](https://writing.codidact.com/questions/275894#answer-275895)

If you would like to copy some of your in scope posts to you can either add to [my post "Import Request."](https://writing.codidact.com/questions/275971) or create a new similar post. They will import the posts for you.